# Blackberry splash screen delay before appears

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-jde

I need to display a splash screen when I app instantiate, I wrote a class for splashScreen based on blackberry develpers knowlwdebase ([link](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800256/How_To_-_Create_a_splash_screen.html?nodeid=800334&vernum=0)).

And its invoked from my following class.My problem is the splashscreen appears only after a deley,How can I solve it,If any one have idea Please help me,Thanks

```
class Test extends MainScreen{

Test(){

UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() {
                UiApplication app=(UiApplication)getApplication();

                Bitmap image = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("splah.png");
                ListView listView = new ListView();
                new SplashScreen(app, listView );

}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock()). It is faster than invokeLater.

```
Test(){
synchronized (UiApplication.getEventLock()) {
UiApplication app=(UiApplication)getApplication();
Bitmap image = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("splah.png");
ListView listView = new ListView();
new SplashScreen(app, listView );

}

}
```